# Why my product photo is not updating? But product title is updating

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I have an update form to update information. Here problem is, `product_title` is updating but `product_image` is not working. Where is the problem that's for why the photo is not updating?

***views.py:***

```
def update_product(request,id):
    product = Products.objects.get(pk=id)
    form = update_product_info(request.POST or None, instance=product)
    
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        print(form.errors)
        messages.success(request,"Successfully product information updated.")
        return redirect("my_products")

    context = {
        'product':product,
        "form":form
    }
    
    return render(request, "update_product.html", context)
```

***update form:***

```
class update_product_info(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Products
        fields = ('product_title','product_image')

        widgets = {
            'product_title':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'style':'font-size:13px;'}),
         
            'product_image':forms.FileInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'style':'font-size:13px;'})
        }
```

***template:***

```
<form action="" method="POST" class="needs-validation" style="font-size: 13px;" novalidate="" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
                           
                           
     <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark ms-auto" value="Update" style="font-size: 13px;">Add</button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass *both* `request.POST` and `request.FILES` to the form:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404


def update_product(request, id):
    product = get_object_or_404(Products, pk=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = update_product_info(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=product)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Successfully product information updated.')
            return redirect('my_products')
    else:
        form = update_product_info(instance=product)
    context = {'product': product, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'update_product.html', context)
```

---

> **Note**: It is often better to use [**`get_object_or_404(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404),
> then to use [**`.get(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) directly. In case the object does not exists,
> for example because the user altered the URL themselves, the `get_object_or_404(…)` will result in returning a *HTTP 404 Not Found* response, whereas using
> `.get(…)` will result in a *HTTP 500 Server Error*.

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Product` instead of <s>`Products`</s>.

---

> **Note**: Usually a `Form` or a `ModelForm` ends with a `…Form` suffix,
> to avoid collisions with the name of the model, and to make it clear that we are
> working with a *form*. Therefore it might be better to use `ProductInfoForm` instead of
> <s>`update_product_info`</s>.